# Parse, Android; relation.getQuery() in ParseQuery Adapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

In a ParseQueryAdapter I want to return the relation of an object I am querying.  This is what I have so far; I am executing the query, retrieving all the goals created by the current user; in public View getItemView I am starting to get the relation of the object (goal).  Would I create a for loop, and store the results in an Array?  If so, how could I set the text in the list?  Thanks so much for your help!

```
public class GoalDetailViewAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    protected ParseObject mPracticeName;



    public GoalDetailViewAdapter(Context context) {




        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            public ParseQuery create() {
                // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                // midwives
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("goal");
                query.whereEqualTo("createdby", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

                return query;
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_goal_detail_view, null);

        }

        //use midwifefirm as item view/list

        super.getItemView(object, view, parent);


        // find in layout the practice name
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalname);

        //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
        titleTextView.setText(object.getString("goalname"));


        TextView practiceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicename);

        ParseRelation relation = object.getRelation("practicerelation");


        relation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List list, ParseException e) {
                if (e !=null) {
                    //error

                }

                else {


                }
            }


        });



        /*mAddGoal = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addgoal);
        mAddGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), AddGoal.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }


        });*/

        return view;
```

Comment: How about showing the goals, and when clicked, open a new Activity/Fragment to show the data from the relation?

Comment: @cYrixmorten in a previous screen I show the goals; this is a detail view showing more information about them

Comment: But fetching relations for each goal seems inefficient, I would think you would only want to show the relations for one selected goal. Anyways,.. `relation.getQuery().findInBackground` is an asynchronous call, so it should happen somewhere else than `getItemView`, as when `getItemView` returns the view to be displayed, `findInBackground` has not yet completed.

Comment: @cYrixmorten yes, I just want to show one relation for each goal

Comment: A relation is normally a list (possibly large) of pointers. What do you wish to show from the relation. I mean what information do you store in practice relation?

Comment: @cYrixmorten basically, each person enters a goal, then a set of steps or practices to achieve that goal, so there could be more than one step...it seemed natural for these to be their own table, otherwise the goal would have step1, step2, step3, etc..but maybe not..

Comment: I have just added an answer that perserves the idea of having a separate table for the steps, but if these steps you mention are simply strinngvalues, then you might just as well have a stringarray to store the steps directly on a goal. In that case, my answer still applies, though then it is not necessary to call `query.include()` anymore.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I will do as you suggest; it does seem like a more efficient setup to have pointers; I probably misread the Parse docs because I remember setting that up as a relation was intentional

Comment: Relations should work better when the amount of relations/pointers are large, but this also means that you have to query them separately (as you were trying to do in your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that I understand your situation I am ready to come up with an answer.

What you need to do (in my opinion at least) is to change your relation to an array of pointers. As long as you do not store beyond several 100's of pointers, then there should be no noticeable performance problems with this design.

The huge benefit of having an array of pointers over relations is that they can be included directly in a query.

Now you can do something like this:

```
public class GoalDetailViewAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    protected ParseObject mPracticeName;



    public GoalDetailViewAdapter(Context context) {




        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            public ParseQuery create() {
                // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                // midwives
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("goal");
                query.whereEqualTo("createdby", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

                // now all the pointers will be populated with data
                // once the query returns
                query.include("practicerelation");

                return query;
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_goal_detail_view, null);

        }

        //use midwifefirm as item view/list

        super.getItemView(object, view, parent);


        // find in layout the practice name
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalname);

        //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
        titleTextView.setText(object.getString("goalname"));


        TextView practiceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicename);

        // now you can iterate the practices directly
        // note that this is not async no more         
        List<ParseObject> practices = object.getList("practicerelation")

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (ParseObject practice: practices) {
            // assuming you have a 'step' col
            // this is just for the sake of example
            String step = practice.getString("step");
            b.append(step);
            b.append(",");
        }

        practiceTextView.setText(b.toString());

        return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best way to do it, but especially considering the FindInBackground being Async and executing a synced Find that might slow down your UI I could suggest the following

```
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_goal_detail_view, null);

    }

    //use midwifefirm as item view/list

    super.getItemView(object, view, parent);


    // find in layout the practice name
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalname);

    //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("goalname"));


    TextView practiceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicename);

    mShowGoal= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.showgoal);
    mShowGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), ShowGoal.class);
            intent.put("goalId", object.getObjectId());
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

    /*mAddGoal = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addgoal);
    mAddGoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), AddGoal.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }


    });*/

    return view;
}
```

So every itemview will have a button (or could be anything you could hook an onclicklistener to) that will start a new fragment/activity and you can pass whatever binds your goal to its specific data

Depending how your data is stored, you might need to pass something else, rather than the objectId.

```
public class ShowGoal extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    String goalId = i.getString("goalId");
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("extrainfo");
    query.whereEqualTo("pointer_column", goalId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
           //Success!
       } else {
           //Failed
       }
   });
}
```

Hope this helps a bit! Cheers